# Update multiple vendor_id from checkbox to database

Tags: laravel

I need to update a selected vendor_id in my database using checkbox but the problem I'm getting is it's not updating all selected it's updating only one felid in the database. Actually I'm working on CRM here I want to send multiple leads to the vendor on checkbox select

**update query in controller**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

    $ids = $request->ids;
    $vendor_id = $request->vendor_id;

    $leads = DB::table('leads')
            ->where('id', implode(',', $ids))
            ->update(['vendor_id' => $vendor_id]);

    
    //dd($leads);

    return redirect('admin/leads')->with('success', 'lead send successfully');
  
}
```

**my blade file is**

```
            <form action="{{ url('admin/sendall-leads') }}" method="POST">
            
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <div class="pull-right mb-2">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary agsign" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Assign Leads</a>
                </div> 
                <div class="card"> 
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">New Leads</h4>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="selectall">
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>
                                        <th>City</th>
                                        <th>Phone</th>
                                        <th>Service</th>
                                        <th>View</th>
                                        <th>Edit</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($leads as $lead)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" class="selectbox" value="{{ $lead->id }}">
                                        </td>
                                        <td> {{ $lead->customer_name }} </td>
                                        <td> {{ $lead->customer_email }} </td>
                                        <td> {{ $lead->customer_city }} </td>
                                        <td> {{ $lead->customer_phone }} </td>
                                        <td> {{ $lead->service_name }} </td>
                                        <td><a href="{{ route('leads.show',$lead->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">view</a></td>
                                        <td>
                                        @if ($lead->vendor_id === NULL) 
                                            <span class="label label-danger">Not Send</span>
                                        @else
                                            <span class="label label-success">Lead Alloted</span>
                                        @endif    
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
                
                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div class="modal" id="myModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">

                                <!-- Modal Header -->
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Send Leads</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Modal body -->
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <strong>Select Vendor:</strong>
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="vendor_id" id="vendor_id">
                                                    <option>Select Vendor Name</option>
                                                    @foreach ($users as $user)
                                                        <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>    

                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                                        <button formaction="/admin/sendall-leads" type="submit" onclick="return myConfirm();" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Modal footer -->
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
```

**my routes is**

```
Route::put('admin/sendall-leads','LeadsController@update');
```

Please help me or suggest me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::table('leads')
  ->whereIn('id', $request->input('ids'))
  ->update(['vendor_id' => $request->input('vendor_id')]);
```